# Planck Mission and the Hubble Constant

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astronomy

I am studying the trouble with the measurements of the Hubble constant. I have already studied the measurements using the Standard Candles and the time delay due to the gravitational lensing.

I found nothing about the measurement of the Hubble constant obtained by the Planck collaboration, only the values obtained. Could you explain me how did they obtain the value of $H_0$? Could you give a me a good review?

Comment: The Planck Collaborators have published somewhere around 50 papers about the mission and the explanation is *definitely* in one of those (I just forget which one).

Comment: May I ask what the objective of your study is? As I understand, the PLANCK calculations accounted for the "dark energy" and produced lower values than the later measurements. Since the dark energy is hypothetical and has not been observed, its use in calculating an experimental parameter is controversial to say the list. Also, while the Hubble parameter is constant in space, it obviously changes in time in the reverse proportion to time since the Big Bang.

Comment: @KyleKanos I tried to read some of these papers...but they are simply to many and to much long. I hoped that there was something in this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01589...but I found nothing.

Comment: Also, I think this question was asked previously, shortly after the results were released. I'd dig it up and link it, but the mobile search is not so effective at that.

Comment: @safesphere I want to study the different techniques used to obtain the value of $H_0$. I like a lot the SN 1a technique because it seems to be really general and model indipendent. However, I also want to study the other techniques.

Comment: @KyleKanos I searched, using as keywords "PLANCK Hubble" but I found nothing. If you know there was a question similar to mine could you link it later? Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the purpose of the study?

Comment: @safesphere I am studying it for a cosmology exam. However, I think it is interesting because if we obtain a good indipendent measurement of $H_0$ we could obtain more information from the CMB.

Comment: Good luck on the exam! Cosmology is fascinating, especially considering that the FLRW model is wrong, that there is no "dark energy" or "dark matter", the CMB is not what they say it is, and the time/energy symmetry is not violated by the expansion of the universe. The modern cosmology is the "Earth is flat" nightmare all over again. Hopefully the new generation space telescope would eventually set the record straight.

Comment: found a thesis on the subject of measurements of constant http://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/dissertations/2011/Yick-Chee-Fong-Dissertation.pdf

Comment: @annav Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I have already found this thesis and doesn't discuss the results of the PLANCK collaboration because it was written before the 2013.

Comment: @Saramago with your last comment here, you seem to imply that the Planck mission would have used a *different* method for obtaining $H_0$ from the CMB? Seems an odd thought to me

Comment: @KyleKanos I am sorry, because I did not explain well. In the linked thesis the relationship between the Cosmic Microwave Background and $H_0$ is not discussed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Planck publications, it is seen that the Hubble constant comes from a fit to the CMB data in a specific model described  [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5062) :

> Within the minimal, six-parameter model the expansion rate
>   is well determined, independent of the distance ladder. One of
>   the most striking results of the nominal mission is that the best-
>   fit Hubble constant H_0= (67+/-1.2)km sec^-1Mpc^-1 , is lower than
>   that measured using traditional techniques, though in agreement
>   with that determined by other CMB experiments

It is referred in the newer publication [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01589) .

> The Planck 2013 analysis  showed  that  the  temperature  power  spectrum  from Planck was remarkably consistent with a spatially flat 
>   ΛCDM cosmology specified by six parameters, which we will refer to
>   as the base ΛCDM model.

The disagreements with other methods are discussed in section 5.4

So a specific cosmological model is used to fit the data.

Comment: see also this https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/lrr-2015-2